# Use of Macaulay Duration to calculate the Funds Transfer Pricing Cost of an Amortizing Mortgage

Tags: fixed-income, interest-rates, asset-pricing, treasuries, banking

I am asked to comment on the Funds Transfer Pricing methodology used by our Treasury to assign a Cost of Funds to a Loan. This is the current methodology:
Let us say there is a 2 year loan with an annual payment and each payment pays down half of the principal (+ some interest).

[image]

The FTP is calculated by Treasury as: `

> SUMPRODUCT(Year,% of Principal,Bank's Borrowing
> Cost)/SUMPRODUCT(Year,Bank's Borrowing Cost)

`

Is this correct?

If it were me, I would just calculate the Macaulay Duration of the Loan and lookup the borrowing cost corresponding to that duration.

Comment: Is the result of the ratio of the sumproduct supposed to be FTP?

Comment: Correct, the 'weighted average' FTP, as they call it.

Comment: Could you plz check what does the formula produce when applied to the given data?